# How to implement a context menu for a <Preference> on android?

Tags: java, android

I have a preference stored in variable "preference":

```
        Preference preference = new Preference(this);
```

I want to add a context menu to be displayed onlongclick. I have already created the menu `/res/menu/pref_menu.xml` and I tried `registerForContextMenu(preference);` but it only works on views. how can I implement it with a preference?

Answer (score 0):

I solved it by register in onPostCreate method:

```
registerForContextMenu(getListView());
```

And set on the certain preference click listener when need to open:

```
openContextMenu(getListView());
```